# Как передать веса классов в SequentialFeatureSelector?

Tags: python

```
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS
```

Модель xgboost classifier

```
XGB = xgboost.XGBClassifier(num_class = 3)
```

Настраиваю отбор признаков

```
SFSres = SFS(XGB, k_features=8,cv=5)
```

Пытаюсь передать веса классов для отбора признаков через  sample_weight

```
SFSres = SFSres.fit(train_data, train_labels, fit_params={'sample_weight':weights})
```

получаю

> TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fit_params'

Как передать веса классов в отбор признаков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "the documentation is incorrect and needs to be updated"

решение:

```
fit(train_data, train_labels, sample_weight=weights)
```